# Gwibber crashing

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Every time I start gwibber[2.0.0, in Ubuntu Karmic], I get a dialog telling me it needs me to log into Facebook. When I hit ok, I get the same dialog, then, when I hit ok, it crashes.

Where are the configuration files for gwibber so I can trash them and start over? I tried apt purging, and deleting the gwibber directory in ~/.gconf, but neither helped.

Comment: Try running gwibber from a terminal and post the ouput.

Comment: Not a solution —in the short term anyway— but you should report the bug (via reportbug or directly to the project's bug tracker) so the developers get aware of this problem and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there was a big bug in Gwibber 2.0 because it reads the font's size from system. If the font-size of the system is non-integer, then int() fails and gwibber crashes.
Is it the same you you are experiencing?

Or,
Delete ~/.gconf/apps/gwibber again as you did. AFAIK this stores the preferences. Then restart gwibber. These are some common ways to make gwibber start when it fails.